# I was writing a backend code and ejs tags were not working. They are working in another file but not in the "login.ejs" file

Tags: html, backend, ejs

SO in express the error.ejs also has ejs tags but they are working but in another file "login.ejs" they are shown with red color in vs code and not working at all. Someone help I am new to express too.

[ejs tags in login.ejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gcGw.png)

I tried checking the node modules reinstalling ejs and even restarting the computer.

Comment: Can you edit to include the whole file? Likely just a simple syntax error, and since EJS isn't fully supported it breaks the linter so it won't give a warning.